# How do you configure mapping template for suggestion field

Tags: elasticsearch, autosuggest

I would like to configure my index or my cluster such that all "suggest" fields on any new types will be mapped as a completion suggestor.

I am on AWS provided elasticsearch 5.1 and hence using the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I have found so far is this. Even though I explicitly specify a type here in the url path, it applies to all types in the index and also future types.

```
PUT /myindex/_mapping/User?update_all_types 
{
  "properties": {
      "suggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion"
                  }
  }
}
```